# Post title is not displaying properly in Masonry

Tags: wordpress, masonry

I have problem in the masonry on http://greeninvites.com/product/ page.
The last masonry item in the first column is spilling to 2nd column. The post title 'YG1 Tools' is at the beginning of 2nd column.
I am having hard time fixing this.

What changes I need to make to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change  bottom margin from 30px to 0px in your css:

```
.masonry .ms-item
{
margin-bottom:0px;
}
```